# Android errors when getting battery info (in a Fragment)

Tags: android, android-fragments

My app has several action bar tabs, this is one of the fragments.It is supposed to display some information about the battery. The errors appear after navigating the app for a bit.Please explain what caused the problem and what should be done to solve it

Here are the errors from the LogCat :

```
05-15 07:24:30.809: E/AndroidRuntime(25883): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-15 07:24:30.809: E/AndroidRuntime(25883): java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED flg=0x60000010 (has extras) } in com.example.mytaskmanager.Battery$1@4185ea78
05-15 07:24:30.809: E/AndroidRuntime(25883):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:755)
05-15 07:24:30.809: E/AndroidRuntime(25883):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
05-15 07:24:30.809: E/AndroidRuntime(25883):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-15 07:24:30.809: E/AndroidRuntime(25883):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
05-15 07:24:30.809: E/AndroidRuntime(25883):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4624)
05-15 07:24:30.809: E/AndroidRuntime(25883):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-15 07:24:30.809: E/AndroidRuntime(25883):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-15 07:24:30.809: E/AndroidRuntime(25883):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:809)
05-15 07:24:30.809: E/AndroidRuntime(25883):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:576)
05-15 07:24:30.809: E/AndroidRuntime(25883):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-15 07:24:30.809: E/AndroidRuntime(25883): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-15 07:24:30.809: E/AndroidRuntime(25883):     at com.example.mytaskmanager.Battery.setare(Battery.java:77)
05-15 07:24:30.809: E/AndroidRuntime(25883):     at com.example.mytaskmanager.Battery$1.onReceive(Battery.java:120)
05-15 07:24:30.809: E/AndroidRuntime(25883):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:746)
05-15 07:24:30.809: E/AndroidRuntime(25883):     ... 9 more
```

and the code :

```
public class Battery extends Fragment {
    private TextView batteryInfo, memoryInfo, procent;
    int  health = 0, level=0, plugged=0, scale=0, status=0, temperature=0, voltage=0;
    String  technology = "";
    boolean present = false;
    ProgressBar pb;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View myFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout, container, false);
        return myFragmentView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        procent=(TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.BatteryProc);
        batteryInfo=(TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.textViewBatteryInfo);
        pb = (ProgressBar)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.progressbar);
        memoryInfo = (TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.memory);
        setare();
        getMemInfo();

    }



    public void setare(){

        procent.setText("Level: " + level + "%");
        pb.setProgress(level);
        batteryInfo.setText(
                "Health: "+health+"\n"+
                "Plugged: "+plugged+"\n"+
                "Present: "+present+"\n"+
                "Scale: "+scale+"\n"+
                "Status: "+status+"\n"+
                "Technology: "+technology+"\n"+
                "Temperature: "+temperature+"\n"+
                "Voltage: "+voltage+"\n");

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        getActivity().registerReceiver(this.batteryInfoReceiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
     }

    private BroadcastReceiver batteryInfoReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            health= intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_HEALTH,0);
            level= intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL,0);
            plugged= intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_PLUGGED,0);
            present= intent.getExtras().getBoolean(BatteryManager.EXTRA_PRESENT);
            scale= intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE,0);
            status= intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_STATUS,0);
            technology= intent.getExtras().getString(BatteryManager.EXTRA_TECHNOLOGY);
            temperature= intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_TEMPERATURE,0);
            voltage= intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_VOLTAGE,0);

            batteryInfo=(TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.textViewBatteryInfo);
            pb = (ProgressBar)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.progressbar);
            memoryInfo = (TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.memory);
            procent=(TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.BatteryProc);

            setare();        
            getMemInfo();

        }
    };
```

Comment: I miss  setare. Where is it?

Comment: one from procent, pb and batteryInfo is null

Comment: I see that, but I don't know how to correct it

Comment: post the layout getview is returning

Comment: I changed the code as suggested in the comments and the app worked fine, I started it lots of times during a day and it was perfect, then again there is the force close and I don't know what are the errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where are the procent, batteryInfo views in your View hierarchy? If they are in R.layout.layout which you are inflating in onCreateView, move the findViewByIds to onCreateView and use myFragmentView instead of getActivity():
ex: `procent = (TextView) myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.BatteryProc);`